# Using ModbusRTU.h, what would cause holding registers all read 0?

Tags: arduino-uno, modbus

I'm working with a 32-Input Modbus RTU module using RS485. I'm trying to read/poll the inputs to check for ON(1) states.  I have tested this module with Arduino UNO, Radzio! Modbus Master simulator, and Modbus Poll -- all worked as expected, (displaying 0=off, 1=on). Using an Arduino Nano with a TTL to RS485 Module like [this.](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T2/images/I/61JTdn25ryL._AC_SL1500_.jpg)

So using the below code, the output is all 0s regardless of input state.  It compiles and runs without errors.

```
#include <ModbusRtu.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// data array for modbus network sharing
uint16_t au16data[32];
uint8_t u8state;

/**
 *  Modbus object declaration
 *  u8id : node id = 0 for master, = 1..247 for slave
 *  u8serno : serial port (use 0 for Serial)
 *  u8txenpin : 0 for RS-232 and USB-FTDI 
 *               or any pin number > 1 for RS-485
 */
Modbus master(0); // this is master and RS-232 or USB-FTDI via software serial

/**
 * This is an structe which contains a query to an slave device
 */
modbus_t telegram;

unsigned long u32wait;

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);//Create a SoftwareSerial object

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  master.begin( &mySerial, 9600 ); // begin ModBus object 9600baud
  master.setTimeOut( 2000 ); // if no answer in 2000 ms, roll over
  u32wait = millis() + 1000;
  u8state = 0; 
}

void loop() {
  switch( u8state ) {
  case 0: 
    if (millis() > u32wait) u8state++; // wait state
    break;
  case 1: 
    telegram.u8id = 1; // slave address
    telegram.u8fct = 3; // function code (this one is registers read)
    telegram.u16RegAdd = 128;// start address in slave 0x0080-0x009F(128-159)
    telegram.u16CoilsNo = 32; // number of elements to read  0x00 0x01
    telegram.au16reg = au16data; // pointer memory array in Arduino

    master.query( telegram ); // send query (only once)
    u8state++;
    break;
  case 2:
    master.poll(); // check incoming messages
    if (master.getState() == COM_IDLE) {
      u8state = 0;
      u32wait = millis() + 2000; 
        Serial.println(au16data[0]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[1]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[2]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[3]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[4]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[5]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[6]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[7]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[8]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[9]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[10]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[11]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[12]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[13]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[14]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[15]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[16]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[17]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[18]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[19]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[20]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[21]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[22]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[23]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[24]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[25]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[26]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[27]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[28]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[29]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[30]);//Or do something else!
        Serial.println(au16data[31]);//Or do something else!
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Could this be caused by the 'Number of elements" to read?
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

This is the 32-input module [manual](https://hepptech-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/p/sid/EU5R4ozC_x5CmcjbD8TwnzcBJ7FuqtWYBE-dN7v-Gh16UQ?e=c30zLW)
and [programming guide](https://hepptech-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/p/sid/EU5R4ozC_x5CmcjbD8TwnzcBJ7FuqtWYBE-dN7v-Gh16UQ?e=wjcT4V)

Code is based on this [example.](https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino/blob/master/examples/simple_master/simple_master.ino)

Comment: Your code would be more readable with proper indentation. Can you clarify what you mean with "never displayed"? What *is* actually displayed? Is the actual amount of received bytes correct?

Comment: What is actually displayed is a 0, not a 1 when the input is ON.

Comment: If you change your code completely, you should added it as an *UPDATE* than total replace your original code.

Comment: What RS485/Modbus interface board you have? other than the Pin2 for RX, and P3 for TX, How do you wire the RE(Receiver Enable) and DE(Driver Enable) pins?

Comment: *"Code courtesy of: [He who shall not be named]"*  No, what that guy does is leech off these sites with an automatic video generation system. Real credit goes to (or more to) one of the authors here of [an ESE Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/462412/274001).

Comment: I am using this RS485 interface board: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T2/images/I/61JTdn25ryL._AC_SL1500_.jpg
I apologize for the code replace and didn't know about an Update.  I've been fussed at before for posting a second too similar of a question.

Comment: I think the library somehow changed the API for creating an [instance of master](https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino/blob/master/examples/software_serial_simple_master/software_serial_simple_master.ino#L60) and deprecated the `master.begin()` in favour of [master.start()](https://github.com/smarmengol/Modbus-Master-Slave-for-Arduino/blob/master/examples/software_serial_simple_master/software_serial_simple_master.ino#L71).

Comment: I found a working solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTanigwP5ow (see link to his blog-bottom) that was very simple using the same two libraries.